# Negative lookahead after space failing in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to remove all sCss attributes not containing a variable that contains `$c_`. It works fine as long as there are no characters before the `$c_`.

I've got the following regex: `[\-a-z]+:[\s\w\d]*(?!\$c_)[^{;]+;`

First 7 attributes should be kept, rest removed.

```
svg{
.fill{fill:$c_mainColorDark;}
.fill{fill: $c_mainColorDark;}
color:$c_red;
color: $c_red;
border:$c_red;      
border:1px solid $c_red;    
border: 1px solid $c_red;
height:em(16); 
margin-right: 10px;}
```

Example on: https://regex101.com/r/1cGPar/1

What am I missing?

Comment: Try [`[-a-z]+:(?!.*\$c_)[\s\w]*[^{;]+;`](https://regex101.com/r/QWTW0I/1)

Comment: Works great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may use a negative lookahead like `(?!.*\$c_)` or `(?![\w\s]*\$c_)` placed after `:`:

```
/[-a-z]+:(?!.*\$c_)[\s\w]*[^{;]+;/ig
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QWTW0I/2)

This way, all matches that have `$c_` after `:` are failed (i.e. no matches will be returned).

Note that `\w` already matches digits, thus, `[\w\d]` can be safely reduced to `\w`.

I also think adding `i` case insensitive modifier will make it a bit safer since `[a-z]` will also match uppercase ASCII letters.